Order in Ruby Rails 7.1.3 wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
I am trying to create a scope that will order by categories.name in the class Service.
Category is the model that contains the name of the service category and I want to sort by the category name field, but I get the following error:
wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

It's wrong?
I have changed all the ways to call mysql order in rails 7.1.3 and I get the same error.
The scope code is:
class Service < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :delete_photo, if: ->{ remove_photo == "1" && 
  photo.attached? }

  attr_accessor :remove_photo

  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :branch, optional: true
  belongs_to :family
  belongs_to :subfamily
  belongs_to :gender_type, optional: true
  belongs_to :category, optional: true
  belongs_to :service_location, optional: true
  belongs_to :base_service, class_name: 'Service', optional: true
  has_many :additional_features, class_name: 
 'ServiceAdditionalFeature', dependent: :destroy
  has_and_belongs_to_many :branches
  has_and_belongs_to_many :employees
  has_one_attached :photo
  has_one_attached :video

  validate :photo_format
  validate :video_format

  after_create :set_sequence_number_after_create

  scope :with_company, ->(company) { where company: company }
  scope :with_branch, ->(branch) { where branch: branch }
  scope :with_owner_or_assigned_branch, ->(branch) { joins("LEFT 
  JOIN branches_services ON branches_services.service_id = 
  services.base_service_id AND branches_services.branch_id = # 
 {branch.present? && branch.id.present? ? branch.id : -1}")
                                                
.where("IFNULL(services.branch_id, -1) = #{branch.present? && 
branch.id.present? ? branch.id : -1} AND 
(services.base_service_id IS NULL OR 
branches_services.service_id IS NOT NULL)") }

scope :left_join_branch, ->(branch) { joins("LEFT JOIN 
branches_services ON branches_services.service_id = services.id 
AND branches_services.branch_id = #{branch.present? && 
branch.id.present? ? branch.id : -1}").select("services.*, 
IF(branches_services.branch_id IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) AS 
is_selected") }

scope :inner_join_employee, ->(employee) { 
joins(:employees).where(employees: { id: employee }).distinct }
scope :left_join_employee, ->(employee) { joins("LEFT JOIN 
employees_services ON employees_services.service_id = 
services.id AND employees_services.employee_id = # 
{employee.present? ? employee.id : -1}").select("services.*, 
IF(employees_services.employee_id IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) AS 
is_selected") }
scope :with_gender_type, ->(gender_type) { where("(# 
{gender_type} = 3 AND gender_type_id IS NULL) OR gender_type_id 
= #{gender_type}") }
scope :with_category, ->(category) { where category: category }
scope :ordered, -> { order recurrent: :desc }
scope :inner_join_subfamily, -> { 
joins(:family).joins(:subfamily).select("services.*, 
CONCAT(IFNULL(CONCAT(services.internal_reference_code, ' - '), 
''), services.name) AS fullname, families.id AS family_id, 
families.name AS family_name, subfamilies.id AS subfamily_id, 
subfamilies.name AS subfamily_name" ) }


  scope :left_join_category, -> { joins("LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.id = services.category_id").select("services.*, CONCAT(IFNULL(CONCAT(services.internal_reference_code, ' - '), ''), services.name) AS fullname, IFNULL(categories.id,  -1) AS category_id, IFNULL(categories.name, '--') AS category_name" ) }

  scope :ordered_by_subfamily, -> { order("families.name ASC, subfamilies.name ASC, CONCAT(IFNULL(CONCAT(services.internal_reference_code, ' - '), ''), services.name) ASC") }

  scope :ordered_by_category, -> { order("categories.name ASC") }

  scope :ordered_by_service, -> { order("CONCAT(IFNULL(CONCAT(services.internal_reference_code, ' - '), ''), services.name) ASC") }



  

And it is used inside the controller:
  def set_services_by_company
      @services_categories = Hash.new


  services = Service.with_company(@user.company_default).with_branch(nil).left_join_category.left_join_branch(@branch).ordered_by_category


Please show the code that uses the scope, not just a picture of the error.

I suspect it is the left join on categories -- though you don't show the all the scopes you are using in that call.

Are you sure this code you've given is the correct, latest saved version that triggers the error message you shared? The very last line of code you shared shows ordered_by_category called with no arguments, and yet the error message (which presumably points to that line in the stack trace??) says it's being called with 1 argument.

In the long scope chain
services = Service.with_company(@user.company_default)
                  .with_branch(nil)
                  .left_join_category
                  .left_join_branch(@branch)
                  .ordered_by_category

you call left_join_branch(@branch) with an argument, but the left_join_branch scope doesn't accept an argument.
Changing the scope to
services = Service.with_company(@user.company_default)
                  .with_branch(nil)
                  .left_join_category
                  .left_join_branch
                  .ordered_by_category

might already fix your issue.

It accepts: scope :left_join_branch, ->(branch)

left_join_branch only accepts an argument since the OP changed the question a couple of hours ago...
